# Make cursor visible after startup without moving the mouse

Tags: mouse, remote, mouse-pointer

By default, Ubuntu doesn't show the mouse pointer after logging in, only as soon as the mouse is moved. This doesn't cause problems of any kind normally, however, I don't have mouse or keyboard attached to my computer, instead I control my PC remotely using [Unified Remote](https://www.unifiedremote.com/).

And my problem is that although the remote controlling works, I cannot see where my cursor is because it remains invisible as Ubuntu doesn't seem to consider my remotely manipulated cursor as mouse movements, so it never shows the cursor.

The fix would be a simple command that would run immediately after startup and its task would be merely to make the cursor visible so I can see it when moving it remotely. I've tried many commands in the terminal already, but none of them made my cursor visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully you are still wanting a solution :-)

I got myself a micro PC for Kodi which is sitting behind my TV that is hanging on the wall, so no mouse and no keyboard, like you I use unified remote to control the pc and I ran to the same problem as you.

so, I tried many things and this worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

run it in terminal and restart your PC, so far after every startup the cursor is there to see :-)

Comment: Finally I ended up buying a remote logitech keyboard-touchpad combo just because I couldn't get it work. Right now I'm not at home but as soon as I get there in a few days, this will be my first thing to try this out.

Comment: Guess how I'm writing this! From Ubuntu through Unified Remote on my phone:) finally... yaaay thanks very much!